# Передача параметров методом GET и AJAX

Tags: ajax, get

Решил использовать AJAX для удобства, повешен он на ссылки, данные для запроса он берёт из `href`, который задан как `href="?param=value"`. AJAX же добавляет свой знак вопроса, и запрос выглядит так: `my.php??param=value`

Как бы избавится от ненужного знака вопроса? Можно ли его удалить из `href` или должно быть другое решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1.**
Убрать из ссылки знак вопроса:

```
<a class="test222" href="?param=value">test</a>
$(".test").on("click", function(){
    var params = $(this).attr("href").substr(1); /*param=value*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "some.php",
        data: params,
        success: function(msg){
          /*Ваш обработчик success*/
        }
    });
});
```

**Вариант 2.**
Строку с параметрами сразу добавлять к `url` запроса:

```
<a class="test222" href="?param=value">test</a>
$(".test").on("click", function(){
    var params = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "some.php"+params,
        success: function(msg){
          /*Ваш обработчик success*/
        }
   });
});
```